# How to enhance performance of Xml reading using XPATH in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I have a SQL query that retrieve data from a XML column like this:

```
DECLARE @SessionID int = 13506

SELECT 
    r.value( '@number', 'int' ) AS origNumber,
    r.value( '.', 'nvarchar(MAX)' ) AS sentenceOriginal,
    esv_student_number AS tmpStudentNumberOriginal,
    esv_question_number AS tmpQuestionNumberOriginal 
INTO 
    #tempOriginalAnswer
FROM 
    cbe_exam_student_version
CROSS APPLY 
    esv_original_answer.nodes( '/languageacquisition/staticsentences//statictext' ) AS x( r )
WHERE 
    esv_student_answer IS NOT NULL
    AND esv_session_id = @SessionID
```

The query returns the data fine, but it takes too much time. My question is how to enhance the performance of such query?

This is the query execution plan:

[image]

**PS:** This is my first time to work with XML so please be detailed as much as you can.

Regards,

Comment: Use [XML Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497.aspx) on that column

Comment: try appending `[1]` to your values, i.e. `@number[1]`